# Bash: nested for loops on counters read from files, with decimal numbers

Tags: bash

I'm beginning `bash` script exercises. I am trying to do a nested loop reading variables from two different sources like this:

```
for f in $(<f.txt)
do
    for l in $(<l.txt)
    do
        echo "$f $l"
    done
done

read -p "Press [enter] to continue..."
```

Let `f.txt` and `l.txt` be files like the following:

```
25 
26 
26.8
26.9
27
27.1
27.2
27.3
27.4
27.5
28
29
30
```

and

```
0
0.5
1
1.5
2
2.5
3
```

I'm expecting two numbers separated by a white space, I'm getting a white space followed by what seems to be the second number. It only works as expected on the last iteration of the external loop.

As a beginner, is frustrating being unable to find out why this is happening. Can anybody please point me towards the correct direction?

---

EDIT: Unexpectedly, the DOS line ending was indeed the problem - and being a newbie I fall right into it.

I parsed my input files to get rid of the problem and got the expected output: two nested for loops printing two numbers separated by a space. I take the advantage of the edit to clarify:

expected output

```
25 0
25 0.5
25 1
25 1.5
25 2
25 2.5
25 3
26 0
26 0.5
26 1
26 1.5
26 2
26 2.5
26 3
26.8 0
etc...
```

I am willing to leave the thread open for people coming in - also to discuss what was said by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49452895/2125110):

> First, never use for loops like this; use while loops and the read command to read from a file.

Comment: What do you get, what did you expect? I get a long list, each number from the outer loop combined with each of the inner loop - as I would expect. For testing, 2x3 values would have been sufficient.

Comment: dear user unknown, as I stated: "I'm expecting two numbers separated by a white space", and "I'm getting a white space followed by what seems to be the second number. It only works as expected on the last iteration of the external loop."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never use `for` loops like this; use `while` loops and the `read` command to read from a file.

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  ...
done < f.txt
```

Knowing that, it's a "simple" step forward to call `read` twice at each step, with each one reading from separate file descriptors.

```
while IFS= read -r f; IFS= read -r l <&3; do
  echo "$f $l"
done < f.txt 3< l.txt
```

`read` always reads from standard input, so `<&3` redirects file descriptor 3 to the standard input of this `read` command. `3<` opens `l.txt` for reading on file descriptor 3.

Your code does not run the two iterations in parallel; it iterates over all of `l.txt` separately for *each* line in `f.txt`. (Mathematically, your nested loops compute a cross product of the values in `f.txt` and `l.txt` instead of a dot product.)

Comment: Interesting! I found the syntax I'm using in many answers here on SO. I've runned your code, but it prints this:
    0
    0.5
    1.8
    1.5
    2
    2.5

why is that?

Comment: Looks like a DOS line-ending issue in your input files. `26.8\r 1\r` would appear on screen as ` 1` overwrites the `26` after the carriage return moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Many answers on Stack Overflow are written by people who don't entirely know what they are talking about.

Comment: It may very well be a DOS line-ending. I will try to parse files before sending them to the script.

Comment: I took the time to parse them. Now the output looks like it starts looping, but it loops like 25 0  26 0.5  26.8 1  26.9 1.5  27 2  27.1 2.5. It adds to the first value the second value without looping and does not loop the value 3. I'm even more confused...

Comment: What third value are you talking about? It's very hard to tell what you are seeing based on the formatting limitations of a comment.

Comment: yes, I know. I would like to format code here too. The third value was a typo. I meant value 3 of the second input file. Each couple is a line.

Comment: So, I've tried my first attempt after parsing the DOS line-endings, and I got the expected output.

Comment: The expected output is the cross product. This answer doesn't cross them. Processing them in parallel can be done with `paste f.txt l.txt`, no loop is needed.